# Proof that a real number must occur in the domain between two other real numbers

Tags: calculus

I saw the question stating that if your speed is $v_0 = 0$ km/h at $t=0$ and your speed is $v_{30} = 20$ km/h at $t=30$, then did you ever had a speed of $v=\pi$?

Obviously this is the case as speeds are in the domain of real numbers so $v=\pi$ is possible, but how can you prove that this point MUST occur between $v_0$ and $v_{30}$?

Answer (score 1):

This follows directly from the intermediate value theorem if speed is a continuous function of time.

Comment: It is not necessary to assume that velocities are continuous. By a result of Darboux, if $f$ is differentiable in an open interval, then the derivative $f'$ has the Intermediate Value Property on the interval, even if $f'$ happens not to be continuous. More informally, a derivative cannot have jump discontinuities.